# How does the Deposit-User work?

Tags: discussion, spam-detection

On SU there's the [Deposit User](https://superuser.com/users/43131/deposit) which is suspended for quite some time. And I also know that it is used for spammers, but how does it work? Does the account of the spammer get 'linked' to Deposit? Do the answers get moved there?

Comment: You keep working on your [Anti-spam] badge and we'll keep merging spam users into Deposit ;-)

Comment: @Ivo Flipse: I'm doing my best. ;)

Comment: It's being recognized and appreciated @Bobby

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a method we are experimenting on Super User.

Users can be suspended, or in some serious cases, deleted completely. This is fine to deal with regular or offending users.

Spam users, the robot kind, are working differently. They will create several new accounts, so suspending doesn't really have an effect here. Deleting is good, but we lose potential information about them.

This is why the current experimentation is to merge them into one account, to keep track of their activity, links posted, etc. Moderators can see that this user currently has six (6) questions and 78 answers, all deleted. So far, mostly fed thanks to your own flags.

On other sites, [similar accounts exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74440/what-should-community--mods-do-with-spammers/74444#74444), such as [dev-null](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/3191/dev-null), [The Spaminator](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/6154/spaminator), [404 Not Found](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/7725/404-not-found) and the imaginatively named [Spam User Account](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/users/13005/spam-user-account).

It's also a fun game to see how many scalps we slice.

Comment: Is this merging revertible in the (rare, I admit) event of flag-abuse?

Comment: @Tobias - merging is hardly undo-able. It is only a moderator operation, though. The flags I refer to are the ones for moderator's attention. The flagged post and its writer are then reviewed by a moderator who will take action if necessary. Flags are not enough to trigger this.

Comment: @Gnoupi♦: ah ok, I thought you meant spam flags, too

Comment: @Gnoupi: Sounds like the makings of a sci-fi experiment gone bad: **"Attack of the Super-Colossal Multifarious-Conglomerate Indiscriminate Spam Monster from Outer Space!"** (coming summer 2011 to a theater near you)

Comment: Does replacing the spam text with something like *Deleted spam pending removal* (before the post is deleted by a moderator) bother you in this process? (Like you would then have to go into the revision history to see the patterns. I already figured that, when replacing the title, it should still stand out to ensure others flag it too. Like "Delete me" might not been seen, while "FLAG ME, I'M SPAM" might stand out better?)

Comment: One will exist on Programmers' when I can think of a suitable name ;)

Comment: 10k users can't actually see deleted posts on a user's profile, that's a mod thing

Comment: The deposit users seem to have been deleted on all sites you listed (besides SU).