# Should mods clean up user accounts that have been used for spam?

Tags: discussion, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What should community ♦ mods do with spammers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74440/what-should-community-mods-do-with-spammers)

Obviously we clan up spam posts, but what about the accounts? Is this something that we local mods should be doing? For example, [this account](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/users/842/asif-nazar) is an obvious spam account.

Answer (score 4):

I can't say whether it's the official policy or not, but when I find accounts that have only ever been used to post spam I destroy them.  I do this on such a regular basis that I have to think it would have prompted an email from management if they thought it was wrong.

Comment: Yep.  If they provide nothing but advertisement, if their first act is to spam, I nuke.  If someone answers a question in context, provides a commercial solution that they make, I leave it for the community to punish them.