# Has there been an increase in bot vandalism?

Tags: discussion, spam, vandalism

Over on the [Drupal Answers](http://drupal.stackexchange.com) site, I have seen a bunch of suggested edits that are more than likely from spambots.  I don't recall seeing this behavior before, and it has happened a bunch of times the last two days.

There have been two "types".

The first looks like a user gets created, and this user edits an existing answer and adds in a spam link before another link in the answer.  I have also seen an existing answer get copied verbatim, and a spam link added before other link.

This happened in the following cases:

- [How can I remove the default generated <div> tags in view's result?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29677/how-remove-the-default-generated-div-tags-in-views-result/29686#29686) (the answer is now deleted)
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2103
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2159
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2169
- https://drupal.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/2178

The suggested edits are anonymous edits that totally replace the text with spam links.

I have been rejecting and flagging these as appropriate.

I am curious, though, whether there is an increase in this type of spam on other sites, or if it is just the DA site.  I don't have enough rep on other sites to get the **suggested edits** tab on the **review** page to see if it is happening elsewhere.

Comment: I've seen it a couple of times recently here on Meta, particularly the first type of abuse. It's too hard to say if this happens on Stack Overflow, since most of the users I would be inclined to assume are bots actually have real people sitting behind the keyboard. But that's a whole other problem...

Comment: I've been pretty active in the Stack Overflow suggested edit review tool for the past couple of weeks and I haven't noticed much spam there.

Comment: One example yesterday, [and even accidentally approved](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/264986), @Bill.

Comment: @Arjan Luxury fashion?  Seems totally legit on SO.  ;)

Comment: Yup, @Bill, that must be why two users approved that edit. (Kudos to Sha Dow Wiz Ard [for finding that](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/132732/auto-rollback-any-edits-made-by-a-spammer-when-his-account-get-nuked), by the way.)

Comment: As for your examples: seems the quality filter needs to scan for [BBCode](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/BBCode) too...?

Comment: We've gotten edits similar to these on Android.SE periodically. [Here's one from yesterday](http://android.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/1304). I know I've seen it happen before that, too.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I am not sure your edits are correct.  My recollection (backed up my flagging summary) is that question 29677 had the spam edit made directly to an answer, and question 20893 had the answer cloned to include a spam link.

Comment: @MPD I don't see any suggested edits done for any of the answers for the question 29677, while the question 20893 is the one linked with the first link. The suggested edits I reported here are the spammy ones done this month. You can see the suggested edits you rejected on [this page](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpd?tab=activity&sort=reviews).

Comment: @kiamlaluno, both questions are in my flag summary w/ custom reasons.  The flag on 29677 still points to a valid answer (which suggests the spam edit), while 20893 points to a deleted answer (which suggests the cloned answer w/ the spam link).

Comment: @MPD There aren't any rejected edits for question 29677, or any of its answers.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, I didn't reject the edit.  I flagged w/ custom reason so a mod could take care of the spammer at the same time.

Comment: @MPD You flagged an answer that has not been spammed.