# Mark flags as handled when moderator destroys spam account

Tags: bug, flags, moderator-tools, deleted-accounts, moderation-history

I awoke to find four flags on spam posts on Mathematica.  I handled this directly, by destroying the user account from which they originated.  I note that in the Moderator Tools -- History panel it says that I have handled zero flags today, and my action history shows only the account destruction.  Shouldn't I get some kind of "credit" for handling these spam flags?

(Also, because these flags don't appear as handled from the Moderator Tools it is not easy to find which users flagged the spam, or to reference the spam posts that were deleted.  The Spam flags do appear in the User Profiles as **deemed helpful**.)

(This question is not a duplicate of [Mark all flags against a post as helpful, when the post author’s account is destroyed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190119/158428).)

Comment: Are you advocating for a +1 for each user destroyed or a +whatever would have needed to be handled? I suppose the former would make sense, but the latter seems a little odd since the system handled the duplicate or now-irrelevant flags automatically.

Comment: @bmike At least one "handled flag" count for a destroyed user, and at least a link for each post in the moderator history view.  One "handled flag" count per post would be okay too, but I don't really care about that; it's really a matter of having an easy record of this.