# Why would the users page in the mod tools be showing three flags on a user when there are only two?

Tags: support, flags, moderator-tools

While browsing through the mod stuff, I took a look at the /users page. There I noticed that on the all time stats, my own name was showing with three flags:

> [image: Mithrandir♦ [3]]

So, curious, I clicked to see what those three flags were. So I meandered over there, and - ??? There are only *two* flags there, one of which was mine, a custom mod flag from while we were still in private beta, and another VLQ flag that was retracted:

[image: 1 custom flag, and one retracted VLQ]

So... why would it be showing three?

Comment: 1) What you see when hovering over that number? 2) What you see in your own private flag history page, not via the mod tools?

Comment: @ShadowWizard  - 1.) Absolutely nothing. 2.) That's not what I flagged, that's what flags users have raised on my stuff.

Comment: What page are you seeing the 3 on?

Comment: @bluefeet https://literature.stackexchange.com/admin/users

Comment: How many flags are reported in the top of your profile in https://literature.stackexchange.com/users/58/mithrandir?tab=topactivity? That is, just to the left of the link "Meta User"

Comment: @fedorqui - 2..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I checked the database and this is displaying the correct number of flags.  The discrepancy comes in when you attempt to compare the /admin/users total to the 'total posts flagged' on a user profile.

The /admin/users page says it displays 'Users with Flagged Posts' which technically means the total number of moderator attention flags towards a specific user id.  While the flag total on the user profile shows a count of distinct posts flagged by users.

There is a slight difference in what is being displayed even though the verbiage is similar.

The /admin page includes flags that may be created on a post you didn't create, for example we have some [flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284053/community-deletion-of-comments-should-raise-a-moderator-flag/284058#284058) that can be raised on another users post but raised for comments on it.  Since these can be created on a post id that you are not the owner of, it doesn't appear on the flagged post history page.

It's more of a confusion in the wording about what's being displayed than the wrong data being shown.

Comment: `The /admin page includes flags that may be created on a post you didn't create` - so wait what? Then why are they showing up as flags on me? I'm confused. They should both be counting flags *on posts that were by that user*, unless I'm very mixed up.

Comment: @Mithrandir If you get a lot of comments flagged as rude/not constructive over a 7 day period, then a flag gets raised for moderator to review. That flag _may_ be raised on a post that is not yours because you comment on other posts.

Comment: Oohh, that would make sense. So that leads to the question: why when I click on that 3 does it only show those? Shouldn't it include those flags for comments, also?

Comment: @Mithrandir As I mentioned the users flag history displayed the posts owned by you with flags, if the comment one was raised on a post not owned by you it doesn't display there.

Comment: I know. I'm saying that that's confusing UI. If I click on a link that says three, and I get a page that says two... That's confusing. That's all.

Comment: I agree that it should be clarified and [feature-requests](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) are perfect for that. :)

Comment: [Done](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294872/) :)