# Make clearer the difference between how the /admin/users page and flags on the user count flags

Tags: feature-request, flags, moderator-tools

I recently got [confused](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/294860/why-would-the-users-page-in-the-mod-tools-be-showing-three-flags-on-a-user-when) over how a certain part of the 'Users with flagged posts' works. @bluefeet explained that the number on /admin/users is all flags on a **user's ID**, while if you click that link to see what those flags are, you get a list of all flags on **that user's posts**, which don't always match up.

This is confusing.

So, we should make this better. I thought of a couple ways to do that:

1. Make them both show flags on the **user**.

   Any flags on the user's posts will be associated with the user ID. But a flag on the ID is not always on the posts, such as an auto comment flag. So those flags should be included in the list of flags on that user (which are at the moment on that user's **posts**).
2. Make it clearer that there's a difference.

   Currently, the number shown on the /admin page shows flags on the user. But if you click on the link... It goes to flags on the posts. So we should, somehow, indicate that there's a difference in what's displayed in the two different places, especially as when you click on the link from the **user**'s flags you get a page with the user's **posts** flags.

---

I'd be interested in hearing other suggestions as well.