# Deleting a post shouldn't clear auto-flags about comments

Tags: bug, flags

If a user has too many comments deleted through rude/abusive flags, the system raises an auto-flag on one of the posts where this happened.  This helps moderators notice patterns of behavior that we might otherwise miss.  (Sometimes rude comments are deleted by the community without moderator intervention, and sometimes every mod handles one or two and nobody notices the overall pattern otherwise.)

Today I saw a post with such a flag for User A.  Before we handled the flag, the post was deleted by User B (the author).  I expected the flag -- which is, after all, about comments from User A -- to remain.  **However, the flag was auto-cleared when the post was deleted by another user.**  I'll leave a timeline link in a deleted comment here for moderators.

I think in the past these flags have remained active (and I think they should).

Comment: if the post deleted, the comments won't be visible anymore for (<10k users).  So no longer needed flags should be cleared automatically. For mod flags, it will still there even if the post is deleted

Comment: @redhand those particular comments were already gone because of the rude flags. The point of the auto-flag is to alert mods about a user who does that a lot - on multiple posts. A warning and more review might both be needed. It's that auto-flag that's getting cleared, defeating the purpose of raising it in the first place.