# Why is there so much spam on meta and what to do about it?

Tags: discussion, spam

Recently there are a lot of Spam posts on Meta.

- Why is Meta so "attractive"?
- What can we do to reduce Spam in the future?

Comment: Do what we already do? Seems efficient enough.

Comment: `Why is Meta so "attractive"?` Meta is where all the cool kids are...

Comment: @Bart: There are these sunglasses spam posts. They come all the time. Don't these IPs or accounts get suspended?

Comment: I believe one of the problems is that spam nuked by flags no longer is visible to mods. So those accounts can stay around for a while and post again.

Comment: @Bart: Eventually they'd get question banned without actually needing moderator intervention. The spambots rarely ever post as answers (I've personally only seen a couple cases of that).

Comment: I think the spam rate is constant and was always high.

Comment: @animuson Oh sure. They just get (and use) a couple of tries, where their account could have been nuked after the first one. But all in all it's not such a big deal I think.

Comment: Is it really that much?

Comment: @Bart: Even if the accounts get nuked, nothing hinders them to simply create a new one.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby As we have seen with the guy today. His name was surprisingly similar to an earlier nuked account if I remember well. As I already indicated in my first comment, I don't see this as a big problem.

Comment: @WaffelizedBobby - and that's why we need a [deposit](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60295/how-does-the-deposit-user-work) (or equivalent name) user on Meta.SO. That way, more information would be kept. But in general, it's not as much spam on meta. Especially that it is completely out of topic, so it kinda stands out.

Comment: Qualitatively, I see much less spam hitting Meta than on Stack Overflow, but I think it's more noticeable here due to the far lower volume of questions and answers. It usually gets taken care of within minutes in both places, though, so the current system seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not the meta site who only has spammers. They are on every site.

To stop the spammer each site has a link called "flag" with each question,answer and comments. You only need to click on the flag and select the spam option.  Flag privilege require only 15 reputation.

Update from [sha wiz dow ard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard)'s comment : **6 spam flags** will automatically delete the post and take 100 reputation away from the post author.

Note : **flags** are taken very seriously on each site.

Comment: Note that 6 spam flags will automatically delete the post and take 100 reputation away from the post author - very useful.

Comment: Taking away 100 rep from a new account doesn't hurt that much.

Comment: I have a hard time taking this answer seriously. The asker is not some newbie who doesn't know what flags are, and "what can I do when I see an individual instance
 of spam" is clearly not what he's asking.