# What could cause users to be placed in the penalty box for an entire year?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

Just for curiosity I'd like to ask what are the reasons that a user can have their account suspended or placed into the penalty box for one year?

For example, this [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/686849/christina), although I've seen it several times now.

> This account is temporarily suspended to cool down. The suspension period ends on Aug 2 '12 at 16:27.

The reason given in the user's profile page ("to cool down") is quite hilarious, considering how long the ban lasts.

Comment: When you're hot, you're hot.

Comment: I have mentioned in the past that "temporarily" suspended would seem to suit 30-day suspensions, while "long-term" suspension would be a better fit.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

1. For their *third suspendable offense.*  Typically, the first offense is a 7 day suspension, the second offense is 30 days.
2. For egregious offenses, like being blatantly abusive.
3. When we want to hold someone's OpenID hostage (sometimes used for persistent spammers or low-quality posters that keep creating new accounts).

The suspend reasons are intentionally vague;  they are meant to provide enough information about the suspension to eliminate the [Streisand Effect,](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-account) but not enough information to compromise privacy (public shaming is not, and should not, be part of the punishment).