# Account "*temporarily* suspended" network-wide for the next 10 years, and cannot chat for 3 centuries?

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-suspension

[Ron Maimon](https://stackexchange.com/users/528458/ron-maimon?tab=accounts) has his account "**temporarily** suspended" network-wide, as stated in one of his profiles:

> This account is temporarily suspended network-wide. The suspension period ends on Aug 8 **'26** at 7:47.

His profile at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1349035/ron-maimon). Here is [global profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/528458/ron-maimon?tab=accounts).

---

On his [chat profile](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/23715/ron-maimon), the ban is for **273 years** (3 centuries).

> This user is suspended on the parent site and cannot chat for 99737 days.

---

Does temporary mean for the next 10 years (which is 2026) till his retirement, or is it a typo and is supposed to be '16? Also, why is the chat profile inconsistent, and it reads 99737 days?

Three centuries is quite a while for a "temporary" ban.

---

He was mainly active at the Physics site, where he was blocked probably by talking openly about [cold fusion](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/13734/10968) (LENR), which seems to be [off-topic](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2597/10968) there. Does it mean his ban should be active for the next 10 years across all Stack Exchange sites? If the date is not a typo, should his account be suspended only for one specific site across the network?

---

BTW, [the maximum limit seems to be 1 year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/277515/191655) ([unless it's a spam user with multiple accounts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127342/191655), so it's calculated differently). So if the limit is one year, and this user has been temporarily suspended by [a regular moderator before the limit has been introduced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years#comment923693_284807), should the suspension time be adjusted to the current maximum limits?

Comment: I doubt anyone got a ban (especially a 10 year ban) for simply talking openly about an off-topic subject.

Comment: See [Are suspensions automated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/277500/299342)

Comment: For what it's worth, looks like [he can still use chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/23715/ron-maimon), due to a bug his chat profile is not synchronised with the parent site.

Comment: Also, see [this](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/89?m=5193073#5193073) and following messages.

Comment: For what it's worth, he originally had a suspension lasting until this past August; it was then bumped up another ten years. This is definitely not a typo. At any rate, there's no use speculating why the suspension was extended; that's between Ron Maimon and the Physics moderators/Stack Exchange. His profile also reads *I do not participate on this site any longer, except to respond to comments regarding my own text, if that text is unavailable in another form*, so I'm sure he's not too saddened by this.

Comment: SE isn't the only place to boot him out: ["as I can tell from reading content written by both Ron Maimon and others, it seems that he expressed some ludicrous, totally offensive theories about the Boston Marathon bombing ... and that he repeatedly and offensively harassed people who disagreed with him"](https://www.quora.com/Quora-in-2014-Is-the-banning-of-Ron-Maimon-shaping-up-to-be-one-of-Quoras-most-divisive-issues)

Comment: Also, 10 years is not the limit: [4960 days in the Penalty Box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127342/4960-days-in-the-penalty-box)

Comment: The maximum limit is 1 year when handed out by a moderator. Apparently this particular user must have been so problematic that a staff member handled it (which is also apparent because of the network-wide suspension) and deemed it necessary to invoke such a lengthy suspension. So, barring any further information (which we're not going to get regarding private matters) there is no need to adjust anything.

Comment: I just checked the user's profile. The suspension is now until Mar 18 *'92* at 16:28 (my emphasis). 2092. That's 74 years, longer than it takes to dig yourself out of Shawshank.

Comment: @RobertColumbia You are mistaken. If you look at his chat profile, which is listed in days, it's clear that his ban is until *2292*, not 2092. 100000 days, 274 years, or longer than it takes to get into Shawshank, dig yourself out, die, be reincarnated, and repeat the whole process a couple times.

Comment: @RobertColumbia Please do not unnecessarily draw attention to users using tags.

Comment: @Robert adding to Sonic comment, the only people who "have tags" are Jeff and Joel, the co-founders of Stack Exchange. We really should not add anyone else, ever, to that list. Even Jon Skeet doesn't have a tag anymore. (There used to be, but it was burniated at some point.)

Comment: 2022-02-09: 21 years after [Y2K problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem) and more than 13 years after the creation of Stack Overflow they finally changed to four-digit years. [It now reads](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/4864/ron-maimon): *"The suspension period ends on Mar 18 2292 at 16:28."*. Some trivia: [Astronomy Cast](http://www.astronomycast.com/2022/02/ep-629-the-cost-of-delays/) (of all things!!!!) only recently changed to four-digit years (e.g. for the default MP3 names)

Comment: The corresponding MSE post is *[Years in dates will now display with all four digits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376047/)*.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Some individuals do get very long suspensions. I recall one individual from one of my sites ending up earning a multi-year suspension after multiple suspensions, escalations and infractions.

This specific user was not suspended for any specific subject, but there were behavioural issues. Many of which are in the public record across chat, posts and comments, but many of which were expunged for various reasons.

As @HDE226868 commented, discussion around the escalation path for his suspension is not public record.

> "For what it's worth, he originally had a suspension lasting until this past August; it was then bumped up another ten years. This is definitely not a typo.
>
> At any rate, there's no use speculating why the suspension was extended; that's between Ron Maimon and the Physics moderators/Stack Exchange.
>
> His profile also reads I do not participate on this site any longer, except to respond to comments regarding my own text, if that text is unavailable in another form, so I'm sure he's not too saddened by this. –  [HDE 226868  Sep 21, 2016 at 20:13](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284807/account-temporarily-suspended-network-wide-for-the-next-10-years-and-cannot/284809#comment923638_284807) "

I would assume it is not a typo, and that it is across all SE sites. There are a number of behaviours that would not merit simply a single site suspension.