# Why was my account deleted?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, deleted-accounts

I've created my account on Friday and today I found that it doesn't exist any more.

I don't understand why. I answered two questions; one of them is:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/16490710/2371432

Probably those who deleted the answers don't know about the component I proposed as a solution, because it's very new. The questions are asking how you can convert Delphi desktop applications into Web. WebFMX, the component I proposed, does exactly that.

I see this as a very relevant question and there is perfect fit solution for it. 
Would you please considering reopening the question and restoring my account?

Comment: FYI you posted a link to the same answer twice, not to two answers.

Comment: I see an upvote in this question.

Comment: @hims056: The downvotes are irrational; the OP is using *this* site exactly as it was intended.

Comment: Downvotes could be disagreeing with this statement:  `[t]he component I proposed, does exactly that.  Would you please considering reopening the question and restoring my account?`

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, you could argue that there is lack of research (the FAQ could answer this - both before posting an answer at all, and after the account getting deleted).

Comment: @Karina: The account cannot be recovered.  Just create a new one, using a different OpenID.  However, before posting again, read http://stackoverflow.com/faq and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask.

Comment: @RobertHarvey the DVs are also because people perceived to be spammers don't get much sympathy, even if they are, strictly speaking, unwarranted.

Comment: @djechlin: In all fairness, it's very rare for a spammer to bother to ask for clarification.

Comment: ...unless they are trying to mask their spamminess.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Eh, they don't have the time.  Genuine spammers already know that their stuff is going to be deleted, which is why we don't bother communicating with them before burning their accounts; they never come back.  They're too busy throwing spaghetti against the wall.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think that's a pretty broad brush. Since most of their spaghetti doesn't stick, and since SO is such a vibrant place worthy of their effort in getting them to stick, I wouldn't make any assumptions that they're all the same. I've been dealing with spammers directly for a long time and they are increasingly clever and adaptive.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: I'm just telling you what I've observed.  We have a few persistent spammers that create new accounts and repost their stuff, but it's always the same spaghetti; they have no interest in learning what we're about or making an effort to improve.  This post stands out in that regard; in the time it took to post it, the OP could have spammed 10 other sites.

Comment: @RobertHarvey and I'm just saying it's possible that this question is an attempt to determine how to make spamming on our site ok, disguised as a legitimate altruistic question.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Sure.  But in the end, the result is the same.  Account deletion, game over.

Comment: Thank you very much @RobertHarvey for the clarification. I will create a new account and try to avoid everything that could lead my answers to be found as spam.

Comment: *"it's very rare for a spammer to bother to ask for clarification"*, true, [but not unique](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133199/1-year-account-suspension-without-warning), @Robert.

Comment: Well, some people possess righteous indignation in abundance, @Arjan.

Answer (score 20):

Because you created an account, did a search for questions that might have some relevance to your product, and pasted your advertisement there.

In the absence of any effort to learn what the site is actually about, and make an attempt to provide some content that could be of value to others (other than being an advertisement), we generally just delete such accounts.

Comment: I understand that these policies garantee the quality content found on Stackoverflow. Thanks Robert, I will contribute more in interest areas other than the product I am related to.

Answer (score 19):

I think you've been identified as a spammer, because you used copy/paste to advertise your product on multiple, really old questions. This particular question is almost a year old, and the question is off-topic for the site anyway (all shopping list questions are):

[image]

If you have a genuine interest in helping folks solve problems using a product you are affiliated with, there are definitely less nefarious ways to do it.

Answer (score 8):

You most likely got flagged as a spammer for posting the exact same link to multiple questions.

Additionally, I assume you have some sort of relationship with the product, which was not disclosed [per the FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion).