# Can an account be self-suspended?

Tags: support, account-suspension

Is it possible to obtain a suspension on one's own user account by request?

If so, will the message on my profile make it clear that the suspension was requested, or will it look like I got in trouble?

Comment: I did actually request this facility myself when I found myself spending far too much time on here to the detriment of something else. Jeff altered my openid such that it was impossible for me to log in.

Comment: Nice try, some Stacker's wife/husband

Comment: I'd be sorry to see you go, Tomalak.

Comment: Why not take a couple of weeks off, re-charge your batteries, then decide if you want to carry on participating. No point in making an overly hasty decision when you're at a low ebb.

Comment: Does it really need suspension? Just don't use the site

Comment: @Kev: If only it were that easy!

Comment: Not sure why SE should be wasting resources because of an individuals lack of self control.

Comment: @chown: that's our core audience you're talking about!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know of one case where this was done, so I think most moderators would agree to your request and suspend you, if you wish so. Suspensions are per-site, if you need a network-wide ban an SE employee would be needed.

The suspension notices on the user profile are pre-formulated and [selected based on the reason for the suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-accoun/89027#89027). Moderators *cannot* enter a custom message to be displayed publicly on a user's profile.

Comment: IIRC "to cool off" is the default suspension note. I suppose that's appropriate enough.

Comment: @hammar: I would not want people to think that it had been forced on me. Maybe my ego's too big, but, well, sue me.

Comment: (There are also issues with the fact that the suspension message would be cached in e.g. the wayback machine for all eternity. Talk about an employment hindrance.)

Comment: @Lightness: the publicly-displayed suspension messages are intentionally vague for this very reason. Of course, anything you put in your bio text can *also* be scraped and archived, and we don't usually step in to sanitize that... FYI.

Comment: Seems like adding something in your profile saying that you've asked to have your account suspended to enable you to focus on something else would be wise. This would also reduce poking through twitter or email or blog comments if people know how to reach you that way, as well as clarifying the "to cool off" message added as a result of the suspension.

Answer (score 2):

Given that this is the more constructive version of your [other request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126319/suspension-request), here are my thoughts.

**Answering the title directly:**

> Can an account be self-suspended?

An account can't technically be "self-suspended", in that you don't have the ability to give yourself a suspension.  Suspensions are handed out by diamonds.  So in the most literal sense, no, you cannot.

**Answering the question body directly:**

> Is it possible to obtain a suspension on one's own user account by request?

Yes, this is completely possible.  [As Fabian points out](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/106605/140951), this requires various degrees of diamond and/or SE dev work depending on the scope of the suspension.

However, I firmly disagree with Fabian on the following statement (and this is just me, as a moderator on Stack Overflow, I'm not speaking for the other moderators on Stack Overflow or on the other Stack Exchange sites):

> so I think most moderators would agree to your request and suspend you, if you wish so.

Personally, I would not honor this request.

This is something we're simply not qualified for.

This isn't to be confused with a lack of empathy for a situation where one would want this, but there's too much liability (in as much as we can have given what we do, really) attached to an action such as this.

If you feel that there's a compulsion to be on or a reason you feel you can't be away from Stack Overflow *under your own will*, then that's a behavioral issue, and that's an issue for *you* to deal with.  We are not behavioral therapists.

To even begin to approach that role would be extremely negligent on our part and could possibly do you more harm than good.

Finally, there is the canonical reference on suspensions originally written by Jeff:

https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/

Nowhere in the post does it indicate that a suspension is to be used for users who are constructive to the community.  From that post (emphasis mine):

> Our general strategy is to **discourage specific problem behaviors**, not
> individual users. But sometimes you just can’t seem to reach people,
> and it becomes necessary to place accounts in timed suspension.

Quite simply, you aren't exhibiting problem behavior (and I don't encourage you to do so for your purpose) and as a result, you don't fulfill the requirements for suspension.

Comment: I don't see how it would be negligent. It is common for gambling sites to have a self bar facility. Do you regard that as negligence too? What do you think is the worst that's going to happen from granting these requests?

Comment: @MartinSmith It is negligent on the part of the moderator (in this case me) to fulfill this request when it is not within the scope of their duties.  Also, I've referenced the original blog entry from Jeff on this subject, which should show that issuing suspensions are for *problem behavior*.

Comment: Actually I thought this was a feature request to expand that. I see now it isn't and is just asking about current policy.