# Is it possible to find out reason of suspension for another user?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

A user on Stack Overflow was recently temporarily suspended.  Out of curiosity I read through their posts (both questions and answers) and found them to be of decent quality.  They answer far more than they ask (about a 10 to 1 ratio) and always provides lots of sample code in their replies.  They're polite too.  I can't see a reason for suspension.

So, now I'm curious, and maybe I can even learn something from their experience.  Can I find out why they were suspended or is that strictly between the moderator and the user?

Comment: There was no reason given on the large banner at the top of the user page? E.g. rule violations, to cool down, voting irregularities, etc?

Comment: Yes, it said "to cool down".  I didn't realize that was a unique reason.  I figured everyone sent to a penalty box probably needs some cooling down.

Comment: We give a 'generic' reason to avoid the [Streisand effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streisand_effect), but the actual details are not published. However, it's not uncommon for those suspended to bring it here to Meta, in full metal detail (which I hereby coin FMD). That's when things get interesting.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's an [intentionally vague suspension reason](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-accoun) at the top of the user's profile while the account is suspended.

The moderator is bound by the [moderator agreement](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/moderator-agreement) not to give out info like that; the suspension reason is private, though the user is free to admit why they were suspended (though I generally wouldn't recommend it).

While the user would be within their rights to tell you why they were suspended, I wouldn't pressure them about it. If they want to bring it up they will, otherwise let it go. Just keep following the rules, don't be a jerk etc.

Comment: I would go farther, and say that repeatedly leaving "tell me why you were suspended" comments is itself a flaggable offense.

Comment: @PopularDemand well even one of those comments is a flaggable offense (it's not a useful/relevant comment) but yeah, it borders on harassment as well.

Comment: True. First comment noise/off-topic, further comments offensive.

Answer (score 17):

Please rethink this.

Imagine, you have a bad day, and a random stackexchange site was at your fingers when the effects of the bad day materialized. With the unfortunate effect that you had a suspension for a few days.

Do you really want all other users to be able to gasp at your profile to see what you have done wrong, or do you want this personal information by a selected (chosen) few?

Comment: +1 for a real world scenario

Comment: I imagine some folks would enjoy that scarlet letter of sorts.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: Another good reason for privacy.

Answer (score 15):

There is a short explanation displayed on the user profile during the suspension. That is all the information you get, unless the suspended user chooses to divulge more.

Suspensions are a private matter between SE, the moderators and the suspended user. Moderators don't give out any detail to other user about suspensions.

Answer (score 2):

Other answers have addressed the information part of your question already (you get the short reason in the banner, only).  I'm going to address the other part of your question:

> Out of curiosity I read through their posts (both questions and answers) and found them to be of decent quality. They answer far more than they ask (about a 10 to 1 ratio) and always provides lots of sample code in their replies. They're polite too. I can't see a reason for suspension.

If the suspension was content-related (low-quality posts, plagiarism, rudeness, vandalism, etc), then the moderator would have deleted the offending material (or rolled back offending edits) as part of, or very soon after, handing out the suspension.  *You don't see everything.*  When you look at a profile you're seeing only the *surviving* material.

Am I saying "trust us even though there's no evidence"?  No.  Moderators and community managers can see the deleted material, and the moderator messages that accompany suspensions are automatically copied to the community managers for review.  If there is a problem with a moderator or moderator team, SE will act.