# User account status, such as how to know if user is question blocked

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-suspension

For the first time, I observed a temporarily suspended user.  This status was visually indicated at the top of their user profile page:

> [image: temporarily-suspended]

I have not observed this visual indication for other types of interruption such as being question blocked.

How can I tell if a user is question blocked, answer blocked, or other account status?

Comment: There's a difference between suspensions and post bans, suspensions are manually triggered by moderators, while post bans are automatic. The reason you see a minimal description for suspensions is to avoid the [streisand effect](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23385/avoid-the-streisand-effect-be-clear-about-the-reason-when-suspending-an-accoun), which doesn't really apply to automatic bans (the algorithm is the same for everyone, it's not a subjective decision).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Aside from guessing based on the questions/answers you can see (which excludes anything deleted), you can't.

At the moment the question and answer blocks are only visible to employees.

Moderators (and employees) can also see how many flags a user has against their account and how many accounts have been merged into one profile, but both of those are private information and we have no plans to display them publicly.

Comment: it'd be nice if moderators could see if a user is question banned so we don't have to ping you guys.  Right now we guess based on available information.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker Yeah, I agree. I don't recall what the state of that is off the top of my head and whether this is a shared opinion among the team at this point, though.