# The privacy policy at Physics SE

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

(I read [the SE privacy-policy](https://stackexchange.com/legal/privacy-policy)).

I joined Physics SE and browsing members' profiles I saw [this notice](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/65081/wolphram-jonny):

> [image]

I don't know it it is the real name of the user, but can you tell me what is the reason of this policy, to say publicly the cause of the suspension? Suppose it is his real name, all the world must know that Mr JohnDoe  is not so honest, after all (naughty boy!).

I found this post by a CM [**(Shog9)**](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4241/change-of-policy-make-reasons-for-suspensions-public/4243#4243),  when somebody proposed to make the reason  public , he wrote:

> So basically, you want everyone who makes a mistake and has to have
> their access blocked for a while *to be publicly pilloried for the
> amusement* of passers-by?
>
> That sounds like fun.
>
> But for folks you'd actually like to see return to the site in good
> standing, it's probably a bad idea

Update:

[This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/253372/152859), is *the* justification of the policy, a rational explanation: that is "**the lesser evil**". *This* makes some sense.

And that was *all*  I was asking for. It was a simple and innocent question.

Comment: This got nothing to do with privacy, name, or laws. Users are suspended every day due to trying to cheat. "voting irregularities" is vague enough and doesn't disclose any sensitive or private information.

Comment: If you agree with an answer, mark it as accepted by ticking the "V" besides it. If you want to  comment on an answer, post a comment below the answer. Do not put this into the question.

Comment: Is it really necessary to add in details identifying the user used as an example? I was able to find out his/her identity because I recalled seeing the date of the end of the suspension, but anyone could get to the profile by following through on the links of searching for the username. Is this specific case important?

Comment: It seems that jus asking a simple question is considered an offence, here, by someone. How sad!

Comment: @svetlana why offence? Where did you see someone offended by your question? People (including myself) simply disagree with your ideas and the way you ask. (or edit, still think that adding "that is all I was asking for" into a question is wrong)

Comment: @ShadowWizard, downvoting a question is irrational, downvoting it "*because the way one asks*" is mean and childish. Everyone expresses as one can, especially when not writing in one's own language.  You are not **nice** , sound condescending and arrogant, as if you were the Lord of this site.

Comment: I downvoted this in the very beginning because you suggest to remove the suspension reason and I do not agree with that. Never saw any reason to undo that downvote. The edit part is a whole different thing, I won't downvote due to that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, "*.. I downvoted this **in the very beginning** because you suggest to remove the suspension reason ..*" That is false, you are lying: I checked all edits, OP **never** said anything of the sort in her question, she only added a quote by the CM. Now stop harassing her!

Comment: @user234285 so maybe after the edit (Suppose it is his real name, all the world must now that Mr Wolfram is not so honest, after all) which makes it obvious the OP is against showing the reason publicly, it doesn't really matter now. Also involving privacy policy suggests this. Like I said more than once, this got nothing to do with privacy policy in my opinion. This question could have been asked in a different way, too late now though - sorry if I offended anyone, OP, you or anyone else, but I don't think I made any mistakes or lied here.

Answer (score 11):

Nothing to do with laws.

The reason for suspension is between the user and the site moderators.

Why make it public? Except for satisfying someones curiosity, what good does that do?

Comment: The a suspension has occurred is public information. It is very visible (reputation drops to 1, user can't do anything on the site). The **reason** is between the user and moderators - and there is no good to come out of making that public. There are a few different reasons for suspensions - and being "unhonest" is just one of them.

Comment: @svetlana "voting irregularities" does not mean only being dishonest and using sock puppet accounts to upvote yourself. It might also mean a user who constantly downvote random posts just for fun, user who keeps downvoting other user's posts etc, and is not stopping after being asked by moderators. We can only guess, but like I already comemented before, "voting irregularities" really does not tell much about the actual reason and actual actions leading to the suspension.

Comment: @user77434 - the details are not public. The general "reason" shows up, but the specifics are not public.

Comment: @user77434 - I think you need to look up the definition of defamation. Also "voting irregularities" is massively different from "he cheated 254 points".

Comment: There was a misunderstanding, *'suspended for voting irregularities'* sounds a *superflous* negative detail to me, and not to others. The point is that you seemed to agree that one (the main I would say) of the interpretation of that caption is 'being **unhonest**'. In most forums (*thescienceforum,physicsforums,physicsoverflow*,WR,  etc) **no** comment is allowed, and there is no *Streisend effect*. But, considering the outrage my question has provoked, *you'd oblige me if you deleted it*, I tried but **I**am not allowed. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Your [suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253352/the-privacy-policy-at-physics-se/253372#comment827562_253353):

> writing: "The account is temporarilly suspended... suspension will end Jan 3 '16 at 21..."

is **how suspensions worked** from [April 2009](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/), when they were first introduced, until [April 2011](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23385/259867), when Shog9's feature request was completed. The feature request lays out the reasons for having these terse, canned notices on suspended profiles.

Answer (score 4):

The reason isn't public at all. There is just a general notice to the community so they have some idea what is going on.

It said 'voting irregularities', not who he has serial upvoted / downvoted, or any other inappropriate behavior related to voting.

As Oded said, this has nothing to do with law. And if you sign up and participate, you have to follow the rules. If you don't: feel the consequences.

Comment: So what I say is very true. The message doesn't say anything. And it is his/her own fault. If you play, play by the rules.

Comment: So it is public knowledge a user is suspended for some time, just like in football we know that someone got a red card. Who cares? Also it explains why a user doesn't respond on comments for example.