# Can moderators lock users' accounts?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, user-accounts, moderators

Can moderators lock user accounts?

If so, what are the main reasons that they would do so?

Comment: This has to a dupe of something

Comment: @TheLQ: I checked and did not find any posts similar to this one.

Comment: See also [Jeff's (old) notes on the general process](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23661/what-is-the-point-of-a-30-day-account-suspension/23681#23681).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderators can **suspend** users for a certain number of days. From the [blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/):

> If a moderator has warned you via
> email about behavior, and that
> behavior continues, for a period of 1
> to 365 days, your account will be in
> timed suspension.
>
> - Your account will be locked at 1
>   reputation.
> - Your user page will have a
>   visual indication that you are in
>   timed suspension, and for how long.
> - You will be unable to ask or answer
>   questions.
>
> At the end of this period,
> your reputation will be recalculated,
> and your account will resume as
> normal.