# Please undelete this valid bug report

Tags: discussion, support, undelete

Following some discussion [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87303/sudden-death-phenomenon) I think it's legitimate to ask that [this bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87169/metaso-comments-notification-issue) be undeleted, as it actively contributed to improve Stack Overflow. (Fixed existing bug)

[image]

There is another report from same deleted user but as it didn't really contribute it's less important to bring back, though it contained some valid arguments regarding image upload.

Thanks!

Comment: "closed, fixed, and tested -- thanks :) – balpha♦" so no point keeping it around

Comment: @random same point as keeping around all other bug reports.. so anyone can track the "history" of bugs here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51281/is-it-necessary-to-delete-time-local-closed-bug-reports-on-meta). Like old features, bug reports often get cleared over time, or even soon after resolution.

This happens a lot with freakish one-time incidents, but also with bugs that get outdated (like a lot of the envelope bug reports, for example).

I'm not sure this one really stands out among all of the thousands of deleted bug reports and feature requests for needing undeletion, if the only saving grace is that it resulted in the bug being fixed.

Comment: Thanks, though personally I don't completely agree with removing contents so casually. What about reputation for example? If someone found major bug, got lots of reputation from upvotes on the report, why take it away?

Comment: @Shadow Wizard I warmly recommend that you stop thinking about reputation as long lasting on Meta Stack Overflow, or being "taken away". Because it deals exactly with elements that will require constant pruning to avoid public confusion, it is always subject to eventual deletion. The most active you are, it eventually becomes standard practice to expect a loss of hundreds of reputation per month.

Comment: Thanks, point taken and found valid. :) However, reputation means recognition that you've done something good. Maybe when deleting outdated bug report compensate the OP and those who answered somehow? For example have global "bug list" with column "People who found/helped to fix this"?

Comment: @Shadow, @Grace: Personally, I don't care that much about _rep_ here, but I do care about _privileges_. Before the recent recalc I could see up- and downvotes, and I'm glad that I can have that back soon ...

Comment: @Hendrik I do not deny that privilege loss is very aggravating - I personally had to hit 10k twice here. That said, until you *do* hit 1k, [here's a bit of a long-winded alternative to sate your needs](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68289/can-the-upvote-and-downvote-counts-be-shown-separately/75543#75543).

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm, I for one am comfortable with `status-complete` bug reports being deleted. They have no value for future generations. In very rare cases, a bug comes back in a future release, but then you just file it anew.

The only thing lost is the reputation points for the OP, which is indeed a bit unfair, especially if they put a lot of effort in explaining the bug, or even debugging. But does that make it worth preserving outdated information? I think not.

Comment: I might add that the user was under suspension...so the only users who are really losing rep are the answerers.

Comment: And then, some time later, you're *sure* you have seen the bug report before, but cannot find it, no matter how hard you try...

Comment: @Arjan yeah, true. But I don't think that happens *that* often. Plus if you know that bug reports get deleted as a policy, you won't search for too long.

Comment: @Arjan And yet, sometimes it's that thinking that is *misleading*, since what appears to have been the same as an old bug is actually something completely different. History is nice, but not when it can be confusing.

Comment: Okay, that may be true. Also, deleting allows for starting anew when a bug returns. Currently, an existing `[status-completed]` makes that [a bit hard](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65567/deleted-comments-persist-in-the-global-inbox). Hmmm, I need to give this some thought first!

Comment: What about `[status-bydesign]` then? Those can be quite easy for a quick solution. (Like maybe [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87327/wrong-number-order-closed) should not have been posted, but while it was, it was easy to have some earlier report around.)

Comment: @Arkan I agree that `status-bydesign` questions should probably be kept around.

Comment: I agree about reputation loss but unlike you not comfortable with contents being deleted... per Grace comment on her answer I do understand reputation is not really important here, but still.. it means some recognition of what you've done so it's not good idea to take it away just like that.