# Cogsci deleting my account

Tags: support, user-accounts, account-suspension, deleted-accounts, multiple-accounts

[The SE group, Cognitive Science, keeps deleting my account](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243275/cogsci-account-disappeared) on the basis of an invalid identity. Supposing science was evidence-based, I asked what proof I needed to provide to support my identity and they did not respond but re-deleted the account. What's a guy to do?

Comment: "avoiding suspension [through multiple accounts]" != "invalid identity [as in, using a nickname]"

Comment: Why was your original account suspended? Do you have a link to your first account?

Comment: Jan meant, in a programmer way, "avoiding suspension is not the same as having an invalid identity". Jan's comment may have been slightly snarky, but it wasn't sarcastic, and also, sarcasm and rudeness will not help. These are true statements (it would be difficult to argue that "sarcasm and rudeness help"). As "scientific evidence" that sarcasm and rudeness do not help, consider the votes here and the fact that you've now driven away every last person who came to help (which you may wish to reflect on). Good luck! Keep us posted. :)

Comment: I see this as a feature.  A very successful one.

Comment: I purged most of the comments here because they had nothing to do with the question and many were becoming unconstructive. Please stay on topic and [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice); if you want an extended discussion, take it to [chat](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 21):

[The moderator there stated](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/a/921):

> Your account was deleted since it was created with the intention of avoiding a suspension.

This means you have one of two options:

1. If you know you did something that deserved a suspension, don't try to pretend you didn't - just gracefully accept the consequences and learn from it. You absolutely will not win that battle.
2. If, on the other hand, you know you did not do anything that deserved a suspension, you should clearly and calmly describe your situation and present your case on the cogsci meta. Do not lie, however, as it will only hurt your case. The moderators are not stupid. Bear in mind that mods deal with things like this on an every-day basis and know how to recognize certain behavior patterns.

Based on your suspicious and weirdly insistent injections of "must be some kind of glitch" into your comments there, and your attitude (e.g. "supposing science was evidence-based") here, as well as your unnecessarily defensive comments to Jan above, it seems to me that you know what you did and are trying a bit too hard to hide it. Obviously I have no information on the topic, but it generally pays in the long run to be open-minded and honest, and accept consequences gracefully.

Comment: Jan responding in gibberish to a question. I was frank about their economic status. If I didn't think I could validate my identity I wouldn't mess with this c.

Comment: @timmy26 just stop it. Follow the advice you've been given. Contact the team if you must (there is a contact us link at the bottom of each site within the network) and then clearly and calmly explain your situation. Any further comments, statements, arguments and the like in this post are not going to help anyone.

Comment: I purged pretty much all the comments here, as they had nothing to do with the question or the answer. Stay on-topic, or take it to chat, please.

Answer (score 15):

Suspensions are handed out to address serious issues. You will find them in [Suspension Reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/23366/245167).

What you can do:

- Try to remedy the original reason for which your account was suspended.
- Don't try to circumvent the suspension by creating alternate accounts.
- Ask on Meta (which you have already done earlier and now).
- Use the [Contact Us](https://cogsci.stackexchange.com/contact) link at the bottom of the Cogsci.SE page to contact the community team. Describe the details along with the context of the situation, so that they will review your case.

Answer (score 12):

Moderators tend not to explicitly search for users avoiding suspensions by using sock puppets. Those get discovered if the sock draws moderator attention for some reason, often because the sock exhibits the same problematic behaviour as the original account. At this point the moderator might discover evidence that the new user is the same person as a suspended user, which leads to a much quicker and harsher reaction. But even if there isn't enough evidence that the new user is a sock, continuing with problematic behaviour will inevitably end in a suspension.

Socks of suspended users are discovered due to their bad behaviour most of the time, and only after they draw attention the moderators validate their suspicion with additional data.

Comment: Can't you let me verify my identity as an individual?

Comment: @timmy26 Can you explain what "verify my identify as an individual" means and elaborate on how that is related to the moderator's claim that you created new accounts to get around a suspension? I am unclear on the connection, and I think it would help if you could clarify.

Comment: @JasonC "individual" an actual person not just a new account.

Comment: @timmy26 I don't think anybody is doubting that you are an actual person (although I suppose you could be a relatively well-written bot). Also you have a new account. I am still confused because these are not mutually exclusive: actual people can create new accounts.

Comment: @timmy26 I've suspended your alleged main account a few times myself, so I'm reasonably familiar with it. Based on your behaviour here I'm pretty confident that the CogSci mods got it right.

Comment: @MadScientist great i sound like someone you met before so your going to write me off?

Comment: Strange that the person they met before has close to near the same IP address as timmy26? Nah, probably just a coincidence, nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @euphoriaoverlord You're not a moderator, you don't have access to IP address information about SE users. So why are you posting your guesses here?