# How can I flag this "busty babe"?

Tags: discussion, flags

So, somewhere in the 11th hour of my procrastination session on SE, I came across a profile that, in the info/name box, reads "Busty Babe" in Chinese, according to Google translate.

Inside the box is a very large photo of a Playboy (hardcover?) magazine on a desk, situated beside a bottle of some super manly adult drink and of course a very manly cigar. All very manly.

When I thought, "har har, time to flag", I found no such thing. Especially given that the profile changes are applied network-wide, is/should there be an easier way to flag than to go to a specific site, flag one of the user's questions or answers, click "other" and explain it to a mod? Or is there a flag, and I just missed it?

Oh and of course, here is [the user](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/%E5%B7%A8%E4%B9%B3-%E5%AD%A9%E5%84%BF). Appears this might be "payback" for what must be the longest account suspension I've ever seen or heard of.

Comment: Make a meta post, and mods will handle it.

Comment: Given the stat.s of the profile (numbers of questions/answers/people reached, membership years, badges, etc.) and the year-long suspension with a current reputation of "1", I'm half-curious and half-aghast at the thought of whatever transpired this past January (though from S.E. user activity, I think that I'll forgo inquiring).

Comment: @Alex didn't I do that? :O

Comment: @TechnikEmpire Alex means in the [per-site meta](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/), where the site mods will see it. This here is for SE as a whole, not specific site(s).

Comment: "the longest account suspension I've ever seen or heard of" - you [need to get out a bit more](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/277500/are-suspensions-automated) :-)))

Comment: @randal'thor lol wow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No meta post necessary (though nothing bad will happen if you make one). Just flag one of that user's posts - or one of your posts if they don't have any - using a custom reason. Explain the situation as best you can, making sure to request a specific action (e.g. clear profile contents), and a moderator will take care of it.